# numpy.random.randint slower than random.randint

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random

```
In [27]: import random as rnd

In [28]: from numpy import random as nrnd

In [29]: %timeit rnd.randint(0,5)
859 ns ± 22.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [30]: %timeit nrnd.randint(0,5)
4.53 µs ± 104 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [31]: %timeit nrnd.randint(0,10000000)
4.67 µs ± 116 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [32]: %timeit rnd.randint(0,10000000)
979 ns ± 25.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 16:54:48)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

In my 2nd test case, I have increased the random range to `(0,10000000)`. As the range is larger, numpy should perform better at this test case.

Why is `numpy.random.randint()` taking more time than built in `random.randint`? What extra operations is `numpy` doing here?

Comment: Because it's not designed to generate a single random value, it's for creating numpy.ndarray objects.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga A single value can also be considered as numpy.ndarray object right?

Comment: FYI, that's not just the case for numpy.random, but for almost anything numpy does -- if you're operating in really small spaces (e.g. small numbers of 3D vectors) then even vanilla python will usually outperform it.

Comment: @HansMusgrave I have increased the range in the my 2nd test case. So, in my second test case, it should consume less time right?

Comment: @bigbounty Numpy is for vector operations. Try creating a million random numbers and you'll see the difference.

Comment: @bigbounty almost everything in numpy has larger overhead, but pays off when you are allocating large objects (or even smallish/medium-sized). Try comparing `[rnd.randint(0,5) for _ in range(1000)]` versus `nrnd.randint(0,5,size=1000)`

Comment: @bigbounty the range is practically irrelevant.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I agree with your comment.